# AdaptiveCard clears after Submit in MS Teams bot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I`m having MS Teams bot developed using BotFramework v4.

I have a dialog where the user input is required. For this im showing the following AdaptiveCard. 
[image]

Everything looks fine except when user enters all data and presses Submit and the data processed and bot returns: `return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();` the form in Teams is cleared and all fields become empty, this is not very user-friendly. Is there any way to save this data or at least to hide/delete this message from user?

Thank you

Comment: You could [update the existing card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#updating-messages) with details card. And give Edit option which opens up edit card in [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thank you! How can I make a correct Adaptive Card validation?

I added a validation method to the prompt, and when validation fails I return false. But after this form values are cleared and user needs to enter the data again,,,

Comment: When user click on submit, you receive all the text inputs as part of activity payload. You can validate these values and create another card where these are already filled (set value field). Now update existing card by calling [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#updating-messages).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thank you! Do you know how to correctly update Activity using BotFramework v4? Do I need to create new activity and then use context.UpdateActivityAsync(newActivity) or i should first create a reply to the existing activity, change text and then use context.UpdateActivityAsync(existingActivity)?